# Getting a subclass' java.lang.Class instance without using a constructor

Tags: java, class, reflection, subclass, superclass

The situation is like described below:
I got an abstract class with fields and methods and access to all of them (AModule).
I got another class extending this abstract class (e.g. TestModule), but I don't know / can't get the java.lang.Class instance of this subclass in the superclass without using a constructor delivering exactly this instance.
The subclass type isn't always the same, this is just an example how it currently turned out:

```
public abstract class AModule
{

   private Class<? extends AModule> clazz;

   public AModule(Class<? extends AModule> clazz)
   {
       this.clazz = clazz;
       //this.getClass() will return AModule.class
   }

   public Method resolve()
   {
       return this.clazz.getDeclaredMethods()[0];
       //I want get the fields and methods; e.g. foo() of TestModule
   }

}

public class TestModule extends AModule
{

    public TestModule()
    {
        super( TestModule.class );
    }

    public void foo()
    {
       //code
    }

}

public class ModuleLoader
{
    public static void resolveModule(AModule module)
    {
        //at this point I don't know the class TestModule
        //but I want to invoke foo()
        module.resolve().invoke(module); 
        //module.getClass() will return AModule.class
    }
}
```

I need this subclass instance to get all fields and methods to analyse and invoke them via reflection, as defined by annotations.
Does anyone get an idea to solve this to get back the default constructor, without this super call with the subclass instance?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Simply invoke `getClass()`.

Comment: If I invoke getClass() inside the AModule.class, it won't return TestModule.class, it will return AModule.class...

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: There seem to be two questions at once. First, the question based on the false assumption about what `getClass()` does. `getClass()` always returns the actual class of the instance, regardless of where you make that call. So there is no need to pass the `Class` object from the actual subclass to the superclass. The second question seems to be about how to get the implementation class when all you know is the abstract module class. The answer is, there is no simple way to do that, as classes don’t know their existing subtypes.

Comment: But have a look at [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/ServiceLoader.html) for a standard way to declare and lookup existing implementations of an abstract module (“service”) class.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually rather simple:

```
class Base {
  void foo() {
    ... x = getClass();
```

and

```
class Child extends Base {
  void bar() {
    ... x = getClass();
```

In **both** methods `foo()` and `bar()` ... the *result* of `getClass()` is the class of **this**.

In other words: when you call foo/bar on a **Base** object, then getClass() returns **Base**. If called on a **Child** object, in both methods, the result is **Child**.

Meaning: simply use `getClass()` instead of hardcoding the class name in that constructor!